# how do i resolve error message AttributeError: type object 'Player' has no attribute 'rect'?

Tags: python, pygame

by using  `pygame.sprite.collideany()` i am detecting collision between my sprite and a group . however i keep getting the goddamn error message " AttributeError: type object 'Player' has no attribute 'rect' " . it works for the other groups but not for the player . here is code the error is in the Player class

```
import pygame, os, random,sys
pygame.init()
 
FPS=60

SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode((400,350))
pygame.display.set_caption('caption')

x=100
y=200
vel = 3
width = 25
height = 25
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height):
        super().__init__()
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.vel = 5
        self.image = pygame.Surface((width, height))
        self.image.fill((0,0,0))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = (x,y))
        
   
class B(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x,y,radius, color):
        super().__init__() 
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.color = color
        self.radius = radius
        self.vel = vel
        self.image = pygame.Surface((self.radius * 4, self.radius * 4), pygame.SRCALPHA)
        pygame.draw.circle(self.image, self.color, (self.radius, self.radius), self.radius)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (self.x, self.y))
       
class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__() 
        self.image = pygame.Surface((20,20))
        self.image.fill((255, 0, 0))
        y = random.randrange (10, 290)
        x = 400
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = (x, y))
        self.speed = random.randrange(1,2)

 
player = Player(x, y, width, height)

enemies = pygame.sprite.Group()
bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites.add(player)
score = 0
# main loop
running = True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while running:
    clock.tick(FPS)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE and len(bullets) < 8:
                bullet = B(player.rect.centerx, player.rect.centery, 2, (0,0,0))
                bullets.add(bullet)
                all_sprites.add(bullet)
                
    if len(enemies) < 2:
        e = Enemy()
        enemies.add(e)
        all_sprites.add(e)

    for bullet in bullets:
        if bullet.rect.right < 500:
            bullet.rect.x += bullet.vel
        else:
            bullet.kill()
    for enemy in enemies:
        if enemy.rect.right > 0:
            enemy.rect.x -= enemy.speed
        else:
            enemy.kill()
            print ("L")
            print("u stupid dumbass")
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()


    pygame.sprite.groupcollide(bullets, enemies, True, True)
    
    

    for enemy in all_sprites:
      collide = pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(Player, enemies, True)
      if collide:
        all_sprites.remove()
        pygame.quit()
            
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()            
    if keys[pygame.K_UP] and player.rect.top > player.vel:
        player.rect.y -= player.vel
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and player.rect.bottom < 318 - player.vel:
        player.rect.y += player.vel
    
    SCREEN.fill((190, 232, 220))
    all_sprites.draw(SCREEN)
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

how do i add attribute rect in the sprite class ? thank you

Comment: Please post the full stack trace and also how you are calling `pygame.sprite.collideany()`

Comment: Somewhere, you are using `Player.rect` instead of using a Player object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rect` is a [class attributes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables)- Therefore you must create an [instance](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#instance-objects) of the class `Player`. e.g.:

```py
player1 = Plyaer(10, 10, 20, 20)
```

This creates an object with the attributes and you can access the attributes. e.g.:

```py
player1.rect.x += 1
```